# Setting up chromedriver with selenium [python]

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to set up chromedriver with selenium on Windows 10, but when I try to do

```
pip install chromedriver==2.11
```

I get this error

```
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied:'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp8y9hyfk2'

----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\William\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-js539jmr\\chromedriver\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-i7ipagdt-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\William\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-js539jmr\chromedriver\
```

What do I do to get past this because I need to get webdriver set up as quickly as possible for my work. Downloading it online gave me the same error. I have looked and I have every permission that one can have for editing the files in question, so what could it be?

Answer (score 0):

Just download one from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and access it in your code like this (let's assume you saved it to the desktop):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/User/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')
```

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome webdriver (and several others) come packaged with Selenium. The following opens a Chrome window:

```
import selenium
driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()
```

You can see other packaged drivers with `help(selenium.webdriver)`

```
PACKAGE CONTENTS
    android (package)
    blackberry (package)
    chrome (package)
    common (package)
    edge (package)
    firefox (package)
    ie (package)
    opera (package)
    phantomjs (package)
    remote (package)
    safari (package)
    support (package)
```