# Chromedriver in selenium not working

Tags: python, windows, selenium-chromedriver

I am very new to programming so please be very explicit. I've looked through all the questions on stackoverflow but none have helped. I even tried accessing it straight from the file but every time still get the same error.

[Picture of system variable.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htDgV.png)

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bakat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "C:\Users\bakat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\bakat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bakat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Trumps Twitter Scraper.py", line 13, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "C:\Users\bakat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\bakat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found answer. You have to put the location of executable in the argument of the webdriver

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe)
```

Found answer from Hisagar at

[Setting up chromedriver with selenium [python]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41353684/setting-up-chromedriver-with-selenium-python)

Comment: I was just about to answer here :)

Comment: @Hisagr Thanks so much for the answer though i've spent ages trying to get it to work

Comment: sure, I was glad to help you